# PHP wait wait a variable is different from null

Tags: php, wait

I'm looking for a way to wait my script until a variable is still different from null.Actually, I am submitting a batch job file and I need to wait until I get the id.
I took a look at sleep function, but it seems not matching to my need.
I need to do something like that:

```
<?php
...
$options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
$client = new SoapClient($URL, $options);
$result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data'=>$data, 'process'=>$NameChecker))
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;
while($result=='');
wait;
//execute rest of the php script...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
if($variable === NULL) {...}
```

PHP treats NULL, false, 0, and the empty string as equal.

Comment: I need that the script stops while the $variable is NULL in order to continue the script.

Comment: you can do if($variable === NULL) { exit;}

Comment: @Drugde. I actually need that the script wait until he gets the value of $variable from the server. I was wondering if there is any wait function doing that.

Comment: you mean you need to stop the script until your variable is set ??

Comment: @Drudge.Yeah something like that.